# Eclipse: no active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

In `application.properties`, I specified

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

which should have picked `application-dev.properties` as the profile to activate.

However, when I Run As Java Application in Eclipse, I got the following message.

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default.
```

My best guess is this has something to do with Eclipse. Any comments?

Edit: I have tried Maven Update Project, followed by `mvn clean install -U`, also tried restarting Eclipse and cleaning the project. None of these worked...

Comment: Do you have application-dev.properties file too in your project? If not add that and should work fine.

Comment: @AjayKumar yes I do have it in the project. Under src/main/resources.

Comment: Using profile in Eclipse when starting was working, but a bug in eclipse forced me to restart eclipse to discover the profile. Don't know why Eclipse/Springboot just stopped finding it.

Comment: @Andreas Mattisson Same here. Turned to IntelliJ after all these hassles. Problem gone now:)

Answer (score 12):

I was getting the same Problem.

After adding the below dependency in the pom.xml file, the application starts running.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Each enterprise application has many environments, like: `dev`, `stage`, `prod`.

Every environment requires a setting that is specific to them. For example, the database settings for **dev env** are not the same for **prod env**.

To create multiple environments in spring we should create a properties file for each one.

[image]

***NB:** No matter what type of file you use .properties or .yml, it will work*

The `application.yml` will remain as a master properties file, but if we override any key in the profile-specific file, the latter will gain precedence.

In the normal Spring way, you can use a `spring.profiles.active` property to specify which profiles are active. You can specify the property in any of the usual ways, for example you could include it in your application.yml:

[image]

You should specify the profiles to enable on the command line, if you you need to use multiple profiles make sure to separate them with a comma :

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response but, is there a way to specify which profiles to run without typing in the command line?

Comment: i have the same issue, after adding some dependancies for oauth2 !! please someone solved this issue ?